# Show/Hide content doesn't work on IE10 and below. Div not clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have a [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/vanduzled/aspoLh0g/) which demonstrates an Isotope gallery that when you clicked on, a description will slide up. It works well on Firefox, Chrome and IE 11 but not on IE10 and below.

script:

```
    $('.showhide').click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('showhidenew');
    });
```

CSS:

```
.blurb {
  bottom: 0;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}

.showhide {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.more-content {
  background: #008dee;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 11px 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 5px;
  z-index: 10;

  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.showhide .more-content {
  top: 100%;
}

.showhide.showhidenew .more-content {
  top: 0;
}


.info {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #323232;
  color: white;
  padding: 7px 15px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 11;
}

.more.showthis{
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know why, but in IE10, the image right after the showhide object is blocking the click event (e.g taking it).  I presume you also know that in IE9 and below, there is no support for CSS3 transitions.

Comment: You have any idea why is that? I don't really mind the CSS3 animation. As long as it's clickable and the content appears.

Comment: One possibility here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394848/z-index-in-ie-10

Comment: it's working with all the versions of i.e, you need to do some sanity check..

Comment: @cracker - no it doesn't work on all versions of IE. I have a machine that runs IE9 natively and it doesn't work there.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I tried putting another div with position relative, but still didn't work. I have IE=edge content also since I'm using twitter bootstrap.

Comment: try to reset all the settings of the browser and then check it

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Putting the showhide class under the bits class made the showhide class not clickable. The solution I did was to remove the showhide div and add the showhide class inside the bits class to make the whole div clickable. I also made remove the 100% width on the showhide class.

[Here's an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vanduzled/aspoLh0g/16/)

```
    <div class="bits i-h3 showhide">
        <div class="more-content">
            <div class="info">X</div>
             <h2>Title</h2>

             <h5>Sub Title <br /> Description</h5>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
        <!-- morecontent -->

    <div class="blurb">
         <h2>Title</h2>

         <h5>Sub Title <br /> Description</h5>

    </div><!-- blurb -->

    <img src="http://placehold.it/580x450" alt="M Moser Associates" />
</div><!-- bits -->
```